# Suppress Email Notifications from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, sharepoint-email

I am setting up a SharePoint site for my organization, and part of the configuration includes creating several directories and giving different sets of users access to each.

I would like to share folders with these users without sending them an email notification each time a folder is shared. Is this possible?

[I found a similar question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193567/how-to-disable-email-alerts-that-i-just-shared-something/193573) which mentions a checkbox that I can deselect to prevent an email from being sent. However, the poster of that question mentioned that unchecking that box does not work to suppress the email notification. Is it possible to turn email notifications from SharePoint off while I am setting up these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future, the checkbox mentioned in the related question linked above worked to prevent emails from being sent to users when directories were shared with them. This was done via Classic View on SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SharePoint Online you can setup an exchange mail flow rule to stop the emails, if you are talking about on-prem you can disable outbound email in central admin.